# Debugging NameError in Python Code for Minutes to Hours Conversion

Tags: python, python-3.x

As a Python beginner, I'm facing an issue with the following code intended to convert minutes into hours. I'm encountering a NameError in the code snippet below.

```py
def minutes_to_hours(minutes):
    hours = minutes / 60.0
    return hours

minutes = int(input("Enter minutes \n"))
minutes_to_hours(minutes)
print(hours)
```

The code is designed to prompt the user to input minutes and then convert that value into hours. However, when I run the code and input 120, it raises the following error:

```
Enter minutes
120
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "functions.py", line 11, in <module>
    print(hours)
NameError: name 'hours' is not defined
```

I appreciate any help on what might be causing the error and how to fix it. Thank you!

Comment: `hours = minutes_to_hours(minutes); print(hours)` `hours` is local to your function.

Comment: just use `print(minutes_to_hours(minutes))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"hours" is not defined, because you didn't declare/set "hours" variable!

This is why you getting a NameError because you didn't set the hours value and in minutes_to_hours

If you want to get hours within a def statement, use

```
def minutes_to_hours(minutes):
    global hours
    hours = minutes/60.0
    #return is not setting a new variable, so this will return None
```

Correct code:

```
def minutes_to_hours(minutes):
    hours = minutes/60.0
    return hours

minutes = int(input("Enter minutes \n"))

hours = minutes_to_hours(minutes)
print(hours)
```

Answer (score 0):

The hours variable is only available in the minutes_to_hours function
Do this

`hours = minutes_to_hours(minutes)`

This recreates the hours variable in the global scope